# How to combine between today's date and a specified time in Django/Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a case in my Django :

Variable 't' get data from database. I print 't' variable and the result is 'datetime.time(16, 59, 59)'. It means at 16:59:59.

I want to combine today's date with these time. Does anyone know?

The result that I want is (for example) : 'datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 22, 16, 59, 59)' which is combine from today's date is '2014-10-22' and specified time like '16:59:59'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
datetime.combine(date(2014, 10, 22), time(16, 59, 59)).
```

Answer (score 1):

its what that `datetime.combine` is for and `date.today()` returns todays date :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime ,date , time
>>> datetime.combine(date.today(), time(16, 59, 59))
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 22, 16, 59, 59)
```